# Arrays not matching correctly

Tags: java, arrays

userAnswer[] holds the string of the answer the user types in and is comparing it to answers[] to see if they match up and then spits out correct or wrong. j is equal to the question number. So if j was question 6, answers[j] should refer to answers[6] right?
Then userAnswer[6] should compare to answers[6] and match if its correct. But its giving me wrong answers and displaying the answer I typed as correct.

```
int abc, loopCount = 100;
int j = quesNum, overValue, forLoop = 100;

for (int loop = 1; loop < loopCount; loop++)
{
    aa = r.nextInt(10+1);
    abc = (int) aa;

    String[] userAnswer = new String[x];

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,abc);

    if(abc < x)
    {
        userAnswer[j] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Question "+quesNum+"\n"+questions[abc]+"\n\nA: "+a[abc]+"\nB: "+b[abc]+"\nC: "+c[abc]+"\nD: "+d[abc]);

        if(userAnswer[j].equals(answers[j]))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct. \nThe Correct Answer is "+answers[abc]);
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong. \n The Correct Answer is "+answers[abc]);
        }//else

    }//if

}//for
```

Comment: JOptionPane looks like Java, not C# or JavaScript, so I removed these tags.

Comment: It looks like you're mixing user answers (indexed by j) with questions you're asking (indexed by abc).  Your variable names are atrocious, and thus you appear to be confusing yourself.  Consider renaming your variables to be meaningful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your indices are named poorly, and you mix them up yourself. You want to check `answers[abc]` and not `answers[j]` against `userAnswer[j]`.

Comment: I know...but I was so far into the program Im not renaming them, but I will keep the variables better.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks. Yes I really need to work on renaming variables to something useful. Thats a bad programming habit.

Comment: Jave IDEs can refractor the code for you. Changing a variable name is one of the many amazing things refactoring can do for you.

Answer (score 0):

For question 6 you need answers[5] because arrays are indexed starting from 0. 0 would be question 1, 1 would be question 2, etc.

Comment: that depends. some programmers refer to the first question as question 0 :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `userAnswer` array is scoped by the for loop. If you mean to use the values outside of this loop, you need to move the defintion outside of the loop. Otherwise, you can just use one answer string as right now you are not accessing the values a second time.